# Customizing exception from data provided by excel file

Tags: excel, laravel, exception, import, format

I use Laravel 5.6 and PostgreSQL 11 in order to import data from Excel file to database. How do I customize the sqlstate error message coming from postgres and display it to user?

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the exception and treat it accordingly.
An `SQLState` error can be captured with a `catch (\Exception $e)`.

[Check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to learn about php exceptions if you don't know yet.

[Check this other link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors) on error handling to learn how to deal with exceptions accordingly in Laravel.

Comment: thx, i get the message from $exception->getMessage; and i want to format it in order to know in which column of which model the error was because i have many inserts in a transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your exception using try catch.

```
try {
    //your source code (import excel to database)
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    return "your customize message put here";
}
```

Comment: thx, this is what i did but i want to get the column from the sql message and  display which column was rong

Comment: can you  please paste here sql exception?

Comment: Yes we can do that but it isn't a good practice and won't work all the time.

Comment: the sql exception changes according to columns of the model.so it changes from time to time.i wonder if there is a built-in fuction to get for example the name of the column